# nutch 1.1 schema.xml

Tags: plugins, nutch

I recently downloaded latest version of nutch. (nutch-1.1) While going through its code, I noticed that there is a conf/schema.xml file which defines schema for solr part bundled with nutch.

This schema.xml has *fields* for every plugin.
 My question is, How do I find out, what values a particular plugin is retuning? In other words, if I use a third party plugin (say plugin X) with nutch and wants to add few *fields* in schema.xml, how do I figure out what "plugin X" is returning and if it is string, int, array?

My second question is that, I see conf/solrindex-mapping.xml which is been used by solrIndexer of nutch. This makes me more confused, since not all *fields* in schema.xml are in solrindex-mapping.xml

For simplicity of explaining answer, lets say Plugin X is feed plugin bundled with nutch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Access and inspect the Nutch Index in question
   [View How-To recipe](http://netscienceresearch.com/techrecipes.php)